# Where is the inverse reduce optimization in the Dataset/Dataframe API in Spark Structured Streaming 2.3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

In Spark streaming with DStreams we have
`reduceByKeyAndWindow(func, invFunc, windowLength, slideInterval, [numTasks])`
where you can supply an **inverse function** that will remove the oldest aggregation result (of microbatch) in the window, allowing you to substantially reduce the size of the state over very large windows.

In the Dataset/Dataframe API we have `groupBy(key, window(...)).agg(myAgg.toColumn)` as shown [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Aggregator.html) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#type-safe-user-defined-aggregate-functions)

But is there any way to optimize the state computation time by inverse-aggregating only the old piece and aggregating the new in the Dataset/Dataframe API?